# How to populate DataFrame column from JSON string element in another column

Tags: python, dataframe

I have a DataFrame with a "details" column that I believe is a dictionary. The initial data is a JSON string parsed with json.loads, then converted from a dictionary to DataFrame. I would like to populate a new "affectedDealId" column with the value in data['details']['actions']['affectedDealId'].

I'm hoping I can do this the "DataFrame" way without using a loop with something like:

```
data['affectedDealId'] = data['details'].get('actions').get('affectedDealId')
```

To simplify I've tried:

```
data['actions'] = data['details'].get('actions')
```

But that ends up as "None".

Also data['details'] seems to be a series when I think it's a dictionary before converting it to a DataFrame.

Alternatively, I do later loop through the DataFrame. How would I access that 'affectedDealId' element?

Below is a screenshot of the DataFrame from the PyCharm debugger.

[image: Dataframe in PyCharm debugger]

Answer (score 1):

I'm making some assumptions about details json, but does this help? You'll will have to adjust the `json.loads(x)` key/index to extract the right location.

```py
df['affectedDealId'] = df['details'].apply(lambda x: json.loads(x)['affectedDealId'])
```

Comment: It will help more if you explain your assumptions.

Answer (score 0):

I think with will be great if you could do something like this.

so this create a data frame off your json column by calling the pd.Series

```
data_frame_new = df['details'].apply(pd.Series)
```

and then reassign your data frame by concat your data_frame_new with your existing data frame.

```
df = pd.concat([df,data_frame_new],axis = 1)

print(df)
```

This approach worked for me on a recent project.

your affectedId will be come a column of it own with the data populated.

it may be of help to you.

Thanks